# store orders in database with diffrent id in one click botton

Tags: php, mysql

I am workin on a webshop and  i try to store orders in database. if user select more than 1 products I just can store the latest chosen product in database. is it possible to store more than 1 products with diffrent id in one click ?

I have this on other page "cart.php"

`$pp_checkout_btn = "<a href='pp.php?post=' class='placeraorder'>Placera Order</a>";`

```
  if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
$postf=$_GET['post']; //
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$pris = $price; 
$totalsumma = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
$produkt_id = $each_item['item_id'];
$antal = $each_item['quantity'];// I can store many quantity with this var  with the same id
$storlek = $each_item['size'];
$färg = $each_item['color'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_postf (produkt_id,userid,storlek,färg,pris,total_pris,antal,date) VALUES ('$produkt_id','$userid','$storlek','$färg','$pris','$totalsumma','$antal',now())")or die(mysql_error()); 


    }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

you can insert multiple records like this

```
insert into your_table (col1, col2)
values ('v1', 'v2'),
       ('v3', 'v4')
```